# Where are the Decentralized File Storage Contracts in Ethereum?

Tags: storage, smart-contract, white-paper

In the [ethereum whitepaper Decentralized](https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/#decentralized-file-storage) File Storage are cited as one of the applications, along with others. But looks like that this ideia is not popular, i do not know a single one, in oposition Tokens Systems, Financial Services,  Domains Name Systems DAOs, decentralized data feed,... all bacame reality.

Is there some Decentralized File Storage Contracts in Ethereum? Why this idea do not got traction?

Answer (score 0):

You can basically store anything you want on the Ethereum blockchain, as long as you pay for the storage. The thing is, data storage on public blockchains tend to be expensive, and you can find better solutions. One example is to only store the verification data on-chain and share your files with third parties without having to trust them.

Overall storing file data on-chain would not be ideal since everyone else has to download your data to verify the correctness of chain, and that inflates the chain size overtime, which makes running a full-node much harder.

On another note, I have seen examples like digital notaries that try to store verification data on-chain for later document verification.